# How to zip two arrays into an object in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, hash, coffeescript

I have the following code

```coffeescript
class A

  constructor: (@message) ->

  parse: (paramNames...) ->
    params = @message.split(/\s/)
    for value, i in params
      @[paramNames[i]] = value

a = new A('foo bar dim sum')
a.parse 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'
console.log a
```

Output

```js
{
  message: 'foo bar dim sum',
  first: 'foo',
  second: 'bar',
  third: 'dim',
  fourth: 'sum'
}
```

Everything works, I just feel like the `parse` method could be done a little cleaner. It seems like I'm doing something wrong :S

`parse()` will never be called by a user; it's only used internally within the library I'm writing. It's safe to assume that `paramNames.length` and `params.length` will **always be equal**.

Comment: How could it be cleaner?  It looks perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's [`object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) function does just what you're looking for. Combining that with [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
class A

  constructor: (@message) ->

  parse: (paramNames...) ->
    params = @message.split(/\s/)
    _.extend @, (_.object paramNames, params)
```

If you're not using Underscore, i think your current solution is already very clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Strings replace function, something like this:

```
parse : (paramNames...) ->
    keyCount = 0
    @message.replace( /(\b\w+\b)/g , (match)->
        @[paramNames[keyCount++]] = match
    )
```

It is more efficient than doing the split method and then the for iteration you're using in your code. Just make sure the RegExp I used satisfies your needs, you can change it to whatever you need.

Comment: I think `/\b\S+\b/` would be the inverse of my regex